# PhpMyAdmin error with config file

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, server-configuration

Errors are:

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured,
>   some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.
>   Server running with Suhosin. Please refer to documentation for
>   possible issues.
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] ...  OK
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] ...   not OK [ Documentation ]
>   General relation features: Disabled
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
>   Display Features: Disabled
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] ...      not OK [ Documentation ]
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
>   Creation of PDFs: Disabled
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] ...not OK [ Documentation ]
>   Displaying Column Comments: Disabled
>   Browser transformation: Disabled
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
>   Bookmarked SQL query: Disabled
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] ...not OK [ Documentation ]
>   SQL history: Disabled
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
>   Designer: Disabled
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] ...   not OK [ Documentation ]
>   Tracking: Disabled
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
>   User preferences: Disabled

My config.inc.php file is as follows:

```
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in Documentation.html and on phpMyAdmin
 * wiki <http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net>.
 *
 * @package phpMyAdmin
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'myblowfishpass';

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'dave1';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'mypassword';

/* Storage database and tables */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'wordpress_db'; //the name of my db table
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark'; //does the pma_ need to change to dave1_?
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

/**
 * Defines whether a user should be displayed a "show all (records)"
 * button in browse mode or not.
 * default = false
 */
  $cfg['ShowAll'] = true;

/**
 * Number of rows displayed when browsing a result set. If the result
 * set contains more rows, "Previous" and "Next".
 * default = 30
 */
  $cfg['MaxRows'] = 50;

/**
 * Use graphically less intense menu tabs
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['LightTabs'] = true;

/**
 * disallow editing of binary fields
 * valid values are:
 *   false  allow editing
 *   'blob' allow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'all'  disallow editing
 * default = blob
 */
//$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = 'false';

/**
 * Default language to use, if not browser-defined or user-defined
 * (you find all languages in the locale folder)
 * uncomment the desired line:
 * default = 'en'
 */
  $cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'de';

/**
 * default display direction (horizontal|vertical|horizontalflipped)
 */
//$cfg['DefaultDisplay'] = 'vertical';


/**
 * How many columns should be used for table display of a database?
 * (a value larger than 1 results in some information being hidden)
 * default = 1
 */
//$cfg['PropertiesNumColumns'] = 2;

/**
 * Set to true if you want DB-based query history.If false, this utilizes
 * JS-routines to display query history (lost by window close)
 *
 * This requires configuration storage enabled, see above.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;

/**
 * When using DB-based query history, how many entries should be kept?
 *
 * default = 25
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryMax'] = 100;

/*
 * You can find more configuration options in Documentation.html
 * or here: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config
 */
```

Answer (score 62):

I too had this same problem. clearing cookies and cache worked for me. try it

Comment: Same thing happened to me, wish I had searched here first before wasting those hours.

Comment: yep me too made me laugh how many other people this has happened to

Comment: Thanks man. :)
I wasted hours in searching for solution and this worked for me.

Comment: Logging out and in again solved it, guess it was cookie related

Answer (score 9):

If you are using "create_tables.sql" to create the database and tables, change the tables name `pma__` to `pma_` . (change 2 underscore to 1 underscore)

Or change the tables name in "config.inc.php", `pma_` to `pma__` (change 1 underscore to 2 underscore).
For example, `pma_bookmark` to `pma__bookmark`

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
```

Comment: This tip finally nailed that. Thank you!  I can't imagine why the database phpmyadmin had a mix of both pma_* AND pma__* tables, but it's the first time I've noticed that weird default setup (using XAMPP 3.2.1). `Import has been successfully finished, 17 queries executed. (create_tables.sql)`

Answer (score 5):

VestaCP Team made and successfully tested error fixer for phpMyAdmin (no more annoying message "The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated"). We hope that fix will be useful and will help users.

Page on Github: https://github.com/skurudo/phpmyadmin-fixer

What the script does:

- works from user root;
- changes inside /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php, fixes value;
- makes a backup of /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php in /root folder;
  adds in a mysql pma user / and the table phpmyadmin (if the user "pma" or the table "phpmyadmin" already exists, the script will delete those!);
- download and add table for database phpmyadmin;
- clean temp files, leftover pma.txt (contains password for pma@localhost) and old config;

Comment: Do you any solution for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; //mysql username here
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password'; //mysql password here
```

Try adding the above configuration lines after `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';`

If these also doesn't work then try with a fresh configuration file, may be by copying *config.sample.inc.php*. Do ensure that it has the above mentioned configuration lines. Check that if it works fine and then start making changes to it step by step, if any changes are to be made..

Please note that the username and password you provide should be able to login you from mysql command prompt..

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these steps :

1. Create a database named phpmyadmin Import database
   sql/create_tables.sql
2. Create a user and Grant access for a user to
   that database (GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON phpmyadmin.* TO
   user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';)
3. Locate and edit your config file, enable these lines in your config.inc.php (remove # in front of each lines)

   ```
   /* User used to manipulate with storage */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'phpmyadmin_pma';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'yourpassword';

   /* Storage database and tables */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';

    /* These lines I added-in because they are not exist in the config_sample.inc.php */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates']  = 'pma__export_templates';
   ```

Please note there are two underscores in between pma__ , you need to make sure it is matched the table name in your database

IF you see this error:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] ... not OK [ Documentation ]
User preferences: Disabled

That means your configuration setting is not matched the table's name, or... your user does not have access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Right in the error page, if you scroll down to the bottom. There is a tip telling you to log out and log in again. Doing this will work

Answer (score 0):

to correct the error, click on the message, after that on top you can si link create, click on create and refresh.
this solution work with me.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if you have phpmyadmin database in your mysql server. Phpmyadmin  helps you create its database.

2) Check if you have pma user. If not create it:

```
CREATE USER  'pma'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourPassword';
```

The pma password must be the same as the one given in config.inc.php

3) Give privileges to pma:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON phpmyadmin.* TO `pma`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

4) Clear cache and cookies.