# PHPMyAdmin working but can't receiving "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)" error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using IIS with PHP, PHPMyAdmin and mysql.  They were installed separately.  When mysql was installed, I was given the option to and went ahead with setting a password.  I can use phpmyadmin using the same password, but when I test my database connection I receive the error `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.

I've been all over forums and youtube looking for a possible solution but haven't been able to get anywhere.  I have disabled my firewall and attempted to allow mysqld through it separately and still no results.

PHPMyAdmin resides in my *wwwroot* folder for IIS and mysql is in my *C:/Progam Files* folder.  Is this the possible issue or is this set up okay?

Additionally, I've reviewed my config files and all have the same matching password. My user is `root` and all config files have that as well.  PHPMyAdmin accepts that as the user.

Answer (score 1):

What it seams to me is that your phpMyAdmin is not correctly configured. You lack username and password options thus you cannot connect. You should review: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#basic-settings and look for $cfg['Servers'][$i]['nopassword'] option. It should be disabled. 
P.S.: Do you get username/password prompt from phpmyAdmin ?

Comment: I do receive a user and password prompt when going into PHPMyAdmin.  I use root and the MYSQL password I set up initially and it logs in okay.  The issue is when attempting to connect "native" to the database - MYSQL application disappears right away and when attempting to connect via PHP code I receive the error above.

Comment: So the issue is with your php script not phpmyadmin ?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is working properly, I've checked my php code and I have the same parameters in there as I'm using with PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are giving `user` as username under *config.inc.php* without any password..

You can either provide the correct password for username `user`

or

You can provide the same username and password which lets you login to *mysql* from command prompt..

Comment: This makes sense to me; however, when I opened that file there was no user information contained within it.  Is there a specific string of information I can search for?  I also added a user to MYSQL via PHPMyAdmin with all priveleges with the username user and am still receiving the same error.  When I attempt to log into PHPMyAdmin with the new  user account, I receive a 1045 error, unable to log in.

Comment: [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408281/phpmyadmin-error-with-config-file/13410103#13410103), if it helps..

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find that file.  This was also set to 'root' when I opened the document.  All my config files look to be configured correctly; however, in the phpmyadmin folder, I have a config folder and a config document.  Could this be creating confusion even though they are both set to 'root'?

Comment: i am not sure..on my setup i am not having _config_ folder..you may provide the link from where you downloaded _phpmyadmin_..